# Unsupported form file version: 1.9. The form cannot be opened

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I have a Java project (Netbeans) which got from a friend. It has a JFrame Form. When I try to open that file from the Netbeans (Tried with Netbeans 7.0.1, 7.1.1, 7.3, 7.3.1) it gives me an error.

> Unsupported form file version: 1.9. The form cannot be opened.

[image]

Is there any solution for this ?

When I try to `clean and build` it gives me 2 errors :

1)The following error occurred while executing this line (\nbproject\build-impl.xml:990):

```
<j2seproject3:copylibs manifest="${tmp.manifest.file}"/>
```

2)copylibs doesn't support the `excludeFromCopy` attribute (\nbproject\build-impl.xml:834):

```
<copylibs compress="${jar.compress}" excludeFromCopy="${copylibs.excludes}" index="${jar.index}" indexMetaInf="${jar.index.metainf}" jarfile="${dist.jar}" manifest="@{manifest}" rebase="${copylibs.rebase}" runtimeclasspath="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page on NetBeans.org](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=211658) says that you might be trying to open this file in an older version of netbeans than the one which your friend has. He might have created this project on a new netbeans ide version. Please ask him for the version and confirm it.

Secondly,the only solution for it seems to have your NetBeans IDE updated to the latest version! Please update your NetBeans IDE to version 8.0!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **8.1** version of `NetBeans IDE`